# Why do we need a Borel function in the definition of exponential family?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

See the following definition. I was expecting $h$ to be a $\cal F$-measurable function, but the definition says it is a Borel function. Anyone can help explain why we need a Borel function here ? What difference does it make?

> [image]

Comment: "Borel" refers to the sigma-algebra of the target space. Remember that $h:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: Thanks! So $h$ basically can be viewed as a random variable? Since a random variable is also a $h:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ function,

Comment: Yes $h$ is a (real valued) random variable.